# "Warning: Out of range value for column" inserting a datetime value into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Pulling some data from MongoDB and inserting it into a MySQL database, using Python and the Mysqldb library.

```
+-------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(16)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subject           | tinytext   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

---

```
created_at  = "2012/06/08 11:47:40 -0700"
sql1 = ("INSERT INTO `items` (`description`, `created_at`) VALUES (%s, %s)", (description, created_at)
try:
    cursor.execute(*sql1)
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %s: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
```

---

For the first insert into the database I get a warning, however I don't receive that warning for subsequent inserts.

> conf/db_tools-import.py:53: Warning: Out of range value for column 'created_at' at row 1
>         cursor.execute(*sql1)

How can I resolve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: I dont think MySQL supports the hours offset for the datetime.

Comment: That is not a proper DATETIME value. The format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. Time zones aren't supported at all

Comment: Cool, Thanks.  One more question, how come I didn't get a warning for subsequent inserts and how come the inserts worked?

Comment: I don't know why you didn't get the warning for subsequent operations, but the inserts worked out because mySQL cast the string into a DATETIME as best it could (possibly resulting even in a correct date). It's just a warning - but you can configure the server to throw an error, too ("strict mode")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving an warning because you are inserting a long date into a date field.  The date filed is "YYYY-MM-DD" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

I did my own test in Mysql, take a look:

```
mysql> create table bigtable (created_at date);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> 

Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'created_at' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bigtable;
+------------+
| created_at |
+------------+
| 2012-06-08 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

if you want to avoid the warning, just pass "YYYY-MM-DD" or change the column to datetime,

Good luck

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? I can see in the question that the column is already a DATETIME...

Comment: @DerekLitz the problem was not the datetime,he was trying to insert complete time and the value was truncate and generating a waning

Comment: I had the same problem. Changing the column type from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME fixed the out of range error.