# How to fix "1264 Out of range value for [date] column"?

Tags: mysql

When changing the engine of a table from MyISAM to InnoDB (by running "ALTER TABLE A ENGINE=InnoDB;"), it returned this warning: "1264 Out of range value for column" for a date column. I'm confused as according to the mysql doc, the date data type should have the same size. Can someone please help? The version of mysql is 5.7. Thanks!

### Edit

Somehow it does not like '0000-00-00'

mysql> select * from test;

| test_date |
| --- |
| 0000-00-00 |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table test engine=InnoDB;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

Comment: Provide SQL code for the issue reproducing (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO, 5-7 rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message: one of the values in the column you are altering is out of range to be casted to a `DATE`.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954885/warning-out-of-range-value-for-column-inserting-a-datetime-value-into-mysql) it could be that the format of the value is not `YYYY-MM-DD`. So find out which value is that or change the column type to `DATETIME`.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. somehow, it doesn't like '0000-00-00'.

Comment: There's a MySQL option to accept `0000-00-00` as a valid date. But I wouldn't use that because that is not a date.